# Fiware Wirecloud widget config.xml: what unit is width and height?

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

In the specification config.xml of a wirecloud widget, we can set initial width and height

```
<Platform.Rendering width="x" height="y"/>
```

When I put in something like width 300 and height = 80, the widget gets much bigger and overflows the screen. 
In the specification I only see that the width field defines the width.

http://forge.fi-ware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/FIWARE.OpenSpecification.Apps.ApplicationMashup

I see in example widgets values like 5 and 8. So what unit is the width and height?

Comment: When I add px as units, I get the error when uploading "Error adding packaged resource: Internal Server Error."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WireCloud prior to 0.8.0 only supports columns and row as units. Pixels and percentages are supported from WireCloud 0.8.0 onwards.

See the [documentation](https://wirecloud.readthedocs.org/en/latest/development/macdl_xml/#the-rendering-element) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

If you check your workspace settings, you will see that you may set your workspace grid up by determining the number of columns and rows you want it to use.

I **think** these numbers refer to the workspace grid columns/rows.